# How to get lotus db column names for a view using ODBC

Tags: java, sql, vba, odbc, lotus-notes

I currently have an ODBC connection setup to a Lotus Notes db using the NotesSQL Driver which is used to create reports in Cognos BI 8.4.
I need to query for the programmatic column names (field names) in a view that I've imported into Cognos Framework Manager, since I need a dynamic way of getting all them, but can't figure out how.

There has to be some sort of SQL to do this (other wise how does Cognos Framework manager get all the column names?) I just don't know how.

I'm only familiar with doing this in DB2.

Answer (score 2):

The ODBC function `SqlColumns` will return the column names.  More info can be found here in the [NotesSQL documentation](http://publib-b.boulder.ibm.com/lotus/c2735080.nsf/66208c256b4136a2852563c000646f8c/e39242c7cf8b5d0485256dd7004d8230?OpenDocument).